# database protocol 'sqlite' not supported - Failed to initialize zdb connection pool()

Tags: sqlite

I am using libzdb - Database Connection Pool Library with sqlite database. I am getting following exception :
Failed to start connection pool - database protocol 'sqlite' not supported

After ConnectionPool_start() - it goes in static int _fillPool(T p), in that it is getting falied at above statement
Connection_T con = Connection_new(P, &P->error);

My connection url is as follows : 
sqlite:///home/ZDB_TESTING/zdb-test/testDb.db

Kindly help me with this problem.

Comment: For information about libzdb refer -
http://www.tildeslash.com/libzdb/#home
http://www.tildeslash.com/libzdb/#api

Answer (score 0):

This means that the SQLite library is not compiled into the `libzdb` library. If installing from a distribution, make sure that you select libzdb built with SQLite. If you built libzdb yourself from source, after you run `./configure` make sure the output says, `SQLite3: ENABLED`. Otherwise you need to install SQLite on your system first.